# Accessing a view controller's delegate from a Category on that view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-category

I've created a Category on UITableViewController and was wondering if it's possible to access the tableViewController's delegate, i.e. can I put something like this into my Category?

```
UIView *firstHeader = [self.delegate tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:0];
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work, but is there something along those lines I can use?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Simply got a "Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UITableViewController'" error.

Comment: Ah... just clicked where I went wrong- the delegate is on the tableView, not the tableViewController. Thanks for making me look at the error a bit closer :) In other words, the following does work...  UIView *firstHeader = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate is on the tableView, not the tableViewController, hence the following is what's needed:

```
UIView *firstHeader = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:0];
```